# JMeter Regular Expression to extract number

Tags: regex, jmeter

I want to extract letters-number from response data and tried few regex but none are working.

E.g. the response data (json) will contain something like:

```
"sessionId":"WC-123"
```

And I want to extract value of sessionId i.e. `WC-123` and store it in variable so that it can be used in other tests.

The format of sessionId will not change. It's `WC-(Number)`.

Comment: What patterns did you try?

Comment: "sessionId":"([a-zA-Z]|-|[0-9])" and few other.....

Comment: Each character class – that is, `[...]` – only matches 1 character.

Comment: Have you tried `"sessionId":"([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'"sessionId":"(WC-\d+)"'
```

that should work though i don't know  jmeter

Answer (score 0):

**Expected:** Needs to Get the Session Id values

**Given formats:** `"sessionId":"WC-123"`

We need to create the following regex formats to extract the session Id values

Regular Expression formats

```
"sessionId":"(.+)"
```